# Limit SSH to a range of IP

Tags: ssh, networking, openbsd, filter, packet

I work with OpenBSD and I want to limit the port 22 for all user who have an IP between 192.168.42.40 - 192.168.42.60. But I don't know how to do this.
I need to modify the packet filter ?

(SSH is on my Web Server and my gateway IP is 192.168.2.2)
My network diagram :
[image]

Can you help me find a solution to do that ?

Comment: You want to block access to the servers port 22 for 192.168.42.40 - 192.168.42.60? Or is it some other limit?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with `iptables`

```
#allow the hosts
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.42.40 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.42.41 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.42.42 -j ACCEPT
...# you must specify all of them
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.42.60 -j ACCEPT

#deny everyone else, note the -A (append) option.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

[iptables](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But I don't have iptables on OpenBSD ?

Comment: This looks like the opposite of what the OP **said**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is a (good) job for the packet filter.
It would be helpful if that range would match a [subnetwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) that could be written as an IP address + netmask.  If you need at least 20 addresses I'd round that up to 30 and start at 192.168.42.33, so you'd be talking about subnetwork 192.168.42.32/27, which means that the hosts' addresses range from .33 to .62.  If this is too much you can narrow it down to /28, which would yield 14 hosts, from .33 to .47.  With that in mind you can add

```
pass on <ifname> inet proto tcp from 192.168.42.32/27 to port ssh
```

to `/etc/pf.conf` on the SSH server, where `<ifname>` is the name of the interface on which SSH traffic will be received (e.g. `em0`).  It can be omitted, in which case the rule will be applied on all interfaces.

Please *do* read `pf.conf`'s man page for further details about setting up the packet filter and how it should be configured.  OpenBSD's `man` pages are usually very well written, thorough and often include examples.